# Why isn't Postgres using my gin index?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

With this table:

```
=> \d "user"
                                          Table "public.user"
        Column        |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     
----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                     | not null default nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
 email                | character varying(255)      | 
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "user_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "user_email_idx" gin (email gin_trgm_ops)
```

This query isn't using the gin index:

```
=> explain select email from "user" where email ilike '%j%';
                          QUERY PLAN                          
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on "user"  (cost=0.00..3986.42 rows=11886 width=22)
   Filter: ((email)::text ~~* '%j%'::text)
(2 rows)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index

*Caveats
The only downside of this approach is that the input query must be at least 3 letters, as Postgres will need to be able to extract at least one trigram from the input query in order to use our trigram index.*

Comment: hah! that was it. `explain select email from "user" where email ilike '%jjb%';` finds "Bitmap Heap Scan on "user"  (cost=28.02..49.45 rows=11 width=22)"

Comment: Actually the input must be like `%abc%` `%ab` or `a%` so it's not always three characters.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not actually utilizing trigram index or your version of postgres < 9.1.

```
select email from "user" where similarity(email, 'xyz@gmail.com') > 0.5;
```

where 0.5 is your threshold, 0-completely different, 1-exact match

**UPD:** Consider that you are giving 1 character as matching term, because one symbol can match lots of documents, it may show poor performance